# Buffer Reader in java

Tags: java

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

what this line means

I am learning BufferedReader. I don't know why we using BufferedReader to get input.
what is the difference between Scanner class and buffer class to get an input?

Comment: To avoid having future questions closed as a duplicate, or to get this one re-opened, please show the concrete results from your own research into this question, and use this information to help make your question unique and not a re-hash of the thousands of similar questions and answers that a Google search will easily bring you. The [ask] and [tour] can help you to learn how to best use this site.

Comment: [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/8/index.html) is your friend: [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html), [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)